# How do I link/point to specific objects in C#?

Tags: c#, data-structures, image-processing

I am currently working on a project involving manipulation of binary images on pixel level (thinning, clustering etc.). Many of the algorithms used involve checking the attributes of neighboring pixels. A pixel object defined as:

```
Public class pixel
{
int x, y;
int NumberOfNeighbours;
int ConnectivityNumber;
int ClusterNumber;
}
```

I can create a list containing all the pixels in the image for processing them sequentially but I want to link each of the pixels in the list to their position on a grid to efficiently get properties of its neighbor pixels.

For example, if I have a map[7,7] with 9 pixels [A to I] in the map, 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwHTn.jpg
and I want to check the value of the `ClusterNumber` of each neighbour of each pixel. It seems very inefficient to run through the list 8 times to find the neighbors of each pixel and it would be easier to use the grid to just check the neighbors. Is there a way to reference a `pixel` in the grid so that I can access its properties as a neighbor of the current pixel in the list? I've thought about creating a `int[,] map = new int[width,height]` containing the indexes of the pixels in the list, but this creates a problem when a pixel is removed from the list and map would need to be updated every time a pixel is removed from the list.

Alternatively, is there a way I can link/point to the neighbors of a pixel in the class itself such that (schematically) I could access a neighbor's properties

```
//list[0].NeighborE  == null
//list[0].NeighborNE == B
//list[0].neighborN  == null
//...
//list[1].NeighborE  == G
//list[1].NeighborNE == D
//list[1].NeighborN  == C
//list[1].NeighborNW == null
...
if (list[i].NeighborE.ClusterNumber > 2)
    list[i].ClusterNumber = 2;
```

Any advice/guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public class pixel
{
    int x, y;
    int NumberOfNeighbours;
    int ConnectivityNumber;
    int ClusterNumber;

    //neighbors:
    Pixel _neighborN;
    Pixel _neighborNE;
    ...
    Pixel _neighborNW;
}
```

Here you need to assign all neighbors pixels during initialization. If current pixels is near the edge, you just assign it to null. But do not forget to check null-values when you operate with them.

Comment: Thanks. If I understand correctly this would be a clone of the neighbor pixel and not link/point to the pixel itself. I would need to reassign it if any of the neighbor pixel's properties changes and assign it to null once a neighbor pixel is deleted. If the event (e.g. ClusterNumber changes) happens on the neigboring pixel, how do I point it back to the pixel whose neighbor it is?

Comment: No, you will have a reference to an object if you will simply assign a value such as `_neighborN = myExistingPixel`. Take a look at implementation of linked list and double linked list (you can easily google them)

Comment: I did not know this. I assume it does not work the other way round so that changes to `neigborN` will not be reflected on `myExistingPixel`. How do I change a property of `neigborN`that will reflect on `myExistingPixel`?

Comment: What are your assumptions based on? If you don't beleive it works then just give it a try. When you declare a variable, you don't declare an object, but a reference to the object in memory. Reference doesn't care about the object's internal data state it points to.